# Convert labels(int) into one-hot vectors for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Kindly help me to resolve my error.Thanks

This is my python code:

## shape of Y (199584, 1) and data type is int

`num_labels = len(np.unique(Y))`

`simulated_labels = np.eye(num_labels)[Y]` # One liner trick!

print simulated_labels

Error:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
  1 num_labels = len(np.unique(Y)) # unique labels 681
  2 print num_labels

----> 3 simulated_labels = np.eye(num_labels)[Y] # One liner trick!

  4 print simulated_labels
  5
```

IndexError: index 1001 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 681

Comment: if you have labels missing in Y, they won't be counted by len(np.unique(Y)), try np.max(Y)+1 instead.

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.one_hot` (There are examples in the doc string)